# SharePoint Event when Permissions of ListItems have been changed?

Tags: sharepoint

i need to fire an event (or start a workflow) when the permissions of a List-Element (ListItem) have been changed. "ItemUpdating" / "ItemUpdated" won't fire (since the ListItem itself is not updated, i suppose), so how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible.

Maybe you can take another approach: build an alternate way for users to change the permissions of an item. When the user applies the permissions (using the UI you've built), you can trigger an event, or start a workflow.

Going further, you could replace the default "Manage permissions" option in the ECB and replace it with a link to your custom permissions management UI. More information: http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2007/08/10/moss2007-%E2%80%93-item-level-menus-investigation.aspx